# Changing the startup file of a WPF project

Tags: wpf

I am sure this is a trivial problem, but it's one of which I cannot seem to solve.

I changed the startup file in my App.xaml from `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` to the code below, hoping that this all I needed to do.

```
<Application x:Class="MVVMPrototype.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MVVMPrototype.View.MVVMPrototype.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

However, I then got the following error stating that I need to set the build property to resource as show below. Previously it was set to Page, which is the same as what the MainWindow.xaml was set to.

[image: Resource]

After doing that I then have a compiler error stating that `InitializeComponent();` does not exists in the current context. The only time I know this to happen is when the class / namespace is out of sync between the .cs file and the .xaml file, but this is not the case.

I have had a look at the [StartupUri documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.startupuri.aspx) but I have not found it to be that helpful. I am sure it is something silly I have overlooked. And yes, I have clean and built the project several times with no luck. Does anyone know how to solve it?

**UPDATE:** Seva Titov has solved the first part. But now I have a `TargetInvocationException` with an inner exception of `System.Security.SecurityException` with the picture below (open the image in a new tab if it's too hard to read):

[image: Security Exception]

Any ideas for this one?

Comment: An image of the exception is exceptionally useless.  There is a link at the bottom of the exception window to copy the exception information to the clipboard.  Try that next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I have now figured out what is happening.

As pointed out in the answer by Seva Titov the StartupUri should have the value of `"View/MVVMPrototype.xaml"`.

The `InitializeComponent();` error where it was stating it was not defined in the current context was because of the build action on the properties of **MVVMPrototype.xaml was set to resource, not page**. Originally I thought adding a new Window control solved this, but it turns out to be a red herring since the build action was set as page on the new control - I think that is the default.

The last error with the `TargetInvocationException` and the inner exception of `System.Security.SecurityException` I fixed by toggling the "Enable ClickOnce security settings" under Project Properties -> Security to generate the **app.manifest**.

This gave me the final error that it is unable to find the manifest signing certificate, so I just unchecked the "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" under project properties -> Signing.

This solved my issue. Hope it helps someone else. Please note I have little, if any, knowledge of deployment / publishing, and I am not sure how the last two will effect this.

Answer (score 4):

StartupUri specifies relative file location, and you seem to have a file MVVMPrototype.xaml in folder View, so your code should look like this:

```
<Application x:Class="MVVMPrototype.App" 
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
     StartupUri="View/MVVMPrototype.xaml">
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that and it would still not compile on the `InitializeComponent();` in the code behind. I did switch the build action back to page from resource and it did compile. But I had a runtime of "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation." Both the way you show the `StartupUri` with the forward slash and the way I have shown it above using full stops, it does not complain that it cannot find it.

Comment: Is your MVVMPrototype.xaml of type window?

Comment: Yes it is a Window. And the exact error message is "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context C:\Code\Kinect\Prototypes\MVVMPrototype\MVVMPrototype\View\MVVMPrototype.xaml.cs 23 13" with `StartupUri="View/MVVMPrototype.xaml"` and I have the same result with `StartupUri="MVVMPrototype.View.MVVMPrototype.xaml"`.

Comment: @Darren, apparently App.xaml has nothing to do with the problem. The issue is with MVVMPrototype.xaml. Check if you have other errors, specifically processing xaml file. InitializeComponent method is auto-generated code that you should be able to find in \obj\<architecture>\Debug\MVVMPrototype.i.g.cs file.

Comment: Okay. That is a little odd since it is a blank file, literally just added a Window from the Add New Item Menu and that's it. I could see the InitializeComponent inside the MVVMPrototype.g.i.cs. However, I deleted the window and created a new one with the same name, and that problem is now resolved. But I now have the problem that it compiles but I have a `IOException` when the the application starts stating `Cannot locate resource 'mvvmprototype.view.mvvmprototype.xaml'`. Any ideas? And thanks for solving the other issue.

Answer (score 0):

in the App.xaml

StartupUri="/ProjectName;component/Folder Or Path/File Or Page.xaml">